# How to setup cocos2x console tool path?

Tags: android, macos, bash, cocos2d-x

I setup cocos2d-x as outlines here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801093/Writing-Games-with-Cplusplus-for-Android-on-a-Mac

Setup.py had all the expected output,

> ./setup.py
>
> Setting up cocos2d-x...
>   ->Check environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT...
>       ->COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT is found : /Users/john/Documents/Projects/Cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.5/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
>
> ->Check environment variable COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT...
>       ->COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT is found : /Users/john/Documents/Projects/Cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.5/templates
>
> ->Configuration for Android platform only, you can also skip and manually edit "/Users/john/.bash_profile"
>
> ->Check environment variable NDK_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable NDK_ROOT...
>       ->NDK_ROOT is found : /Users/john/Documents/Projects/Android/android-ndk-r9d
>
> ->Check environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT...
>       ->ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is found : /Users/john/Documents/Projects/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk
>
> ->Check environment variable ANT_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable ANT_ROOT...
>       ->ANT_ROOT is found : /Users/john/Documents/Projects/ANT/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
>
> Please execute command: "source /Users/john/.bash_profile" to make
>   added system variables take effect

but I cannot run cocos directly:

Eg: `cocos`

I always have to type the full path:
Eg:

```
/Users/john/Documents/Projects/Cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.5/tools/cocos2d-console/bin/cocos
```

As a result, I cannot run ./build_native.py etc for generating my android build because it errors out saying : `sh: cocos: command not found`

I ran the `"source /Users/john/.bash_profile"` command that setup.py said I should but it makes no difference.

How do I rectify this ?

(Cocos2dx 3.5)

EDIT:

When I type: "export" in the terminal, I cannot find any lines for setting the environment variables for:

```
NDK_ROOT
COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT
```

How do I rectify this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added cocos console root to the bash_profile manually.

Here how I did :

In Terminal, type:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

It will be opened within TextEdit.
Add these lines :

```
export COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT=/Users/barisatamer/Documents/workspace-game/Engine_Source/cocos2d-x-3.4/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
export PATH=$COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT:$PATH
```