# How to set ANT_ROOT in environment?

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-c++

When I build my cocos I get the error "ANT_ROOT not defined" even though I followed the cocos tutorial.

```
cocos -deploy -p android -release

Error: "ANT_ROOT not defined. Please define it in your environment"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Simplified, clarified and reformatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find where `ant` is installed on your computer and if it's not, then  install it.  Then set the environment variable to the installed location.

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388343/how-to-setup-cocos2x-console-tool-path).

And [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290243/how-to-set-ant-home-with-windows) about setting environment variables.